# Swift 3: Adding subview through a slider action

Tags: swift, swift3, core-graphics, addsubview

I am attempting to use a UISlider to create a subview on value change, however the addSubview() function will not execute. In the code below, there is an addSubView() function which was added as a placeholder. In my testing, the first print function executed correctly, however the subsequent ones do not. There are no errors if both functions are present, however the addSubview() function throws an error if called directly.
Code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import CoreGraphics

class selectorView: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet weak var jointPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var verticalSlider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var horizontalSlider: UISlider!
var jointPickerData: [[String]] = [[String]]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.jointPicker.delegate = self
    self.jointPicker.dataSource = self
    jointPickerData = [["Neck","Shoulder","Elbow","Wrist","Spine","Hip","Knee","Ankle"],["Left","Right"]]
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
//Number of columns
func numberOfComponents(in: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 2
}
//Number of rows
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return jointPickerData[component].count
}
//Data to return for the row and column being read
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return jointPickerData[component][row]
}
//Catpure the picker view selection
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    // This method is triggered whenever the user makes a change to the picker selection.
    // The parameter named row and component represents what was selected.
}
@IBAction func vertical(_ sender: Any) {
    if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 0 {//left
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 0 {//lNeck
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 1 {//lShoulder
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 2 {//lElbow
            lElbowYGlobal.lElbowY = Int((verticalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
            self.addSubView()
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 3 {//lWrist
            lWristYGlobal.rWristY = Int((verticalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
            addSubView()
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 4 {//lSpine
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 5 {//lHip
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 6 {//lKnee
            lKneeYGlobal.lKneeY = Int((verticalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
            addSubView()
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 7 {//lAnkle
            lAnkleYGlobal.lAnkleY = Int((verticalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
            addSubView()
        }

    }
    if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 1 {//right
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 0 {//rNeck
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 1 {//rShoulder
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 2 {//rElbow
            rElbowYGlobal.rElbowY = Int((verticalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
            addSubView()
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 3 {//rWrist
            rWristYGlobal.rWristY = Int((verticalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
            addSubView()
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 4 {//rSpine
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 5 {//rHip
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 6 {//rKnee
            rKneeYGlobal.rKneeY = Int((verticalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
            addSubView()
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 7 {//rAnkle
            rAnkleYGlobal.rAnkleY = Int((verticalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
            addSubView()
        }

    }

}
@IBAction func horizontal(_ sender: Any) {
    if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 0 {//left
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 0 {//lNeck
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 1 {//lShoulder
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 2 {//lElbow
            lElbowXGlobal.lElbowX = Int((horizontalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
            addSubView()
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 3 {//lWrist
            lWristXGlobal.lWristX = Int((horizontalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
            addSubView()
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 4 {//lSpine
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 5 {//lHip
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 6 {//lKnee
            lKneeXGlobal.lKneeX = Int((horizontalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
            addSubView()
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 7 {//lAnkle
            lAnkleXGlobal.lAnkleX = Int((horizontalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
            addSubView()
        }

    }
    if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 1 {//right
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 0 {//rNeck
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 1 {//rShoulder
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 2 {//rElbow
            rElbowXGlobal.rElbowX = Int((horizontalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
            addSubView()
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 3 {//rWrist
            rWristXGlobal.rWristX = Int((horizontalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
            addSubView()
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 4 {//rSpine
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 5 {//rHip
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 6 {//rKnee
            rKneeXGlobal.rKneeX = Int((horizontalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
            addSubView()
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 7 {//rAnkle
            rAnkleXGlobal.rAnkleX = Int((horizontalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
            addSubView()
        }
    }
}
/*func drawLineFromPointToPoint(startX: Int, toEndingX endX: Int, startingY startY: Int, toEndingY endY: Int, ofColor lineColor: UIColor, widthOfLine lineWidth: CGFloat, inView view: UIView) {

    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: startX, y: startY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: endX, y: endY))

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = lineColor.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth

    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

}*/
func addSubView(){
    print("subview requested")
func addSubview(_ preview: UIView) {
    print("processing request")
    let preview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 127, width: 1198, height: 449))
    preview.center = CGPoint(x: 1198/2, y: 127+449/2)
    preview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    preview.clipsToBounds = true
    self.view.addSubview(preview)
    let circle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 560, y: 10.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0))

    circle.center = CGPoint(x: 560, y: 60)
    circle.layer.cornerRadius = 50
    circle.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    circle.clipsToBounds = true

    let circle2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 25.0, y: 25.0, width: 90.0, height: 90.0))

    circle2.center = circle.center
    circle2.layer.cornerRadius = 45
    circle2.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    circle2.clipsToBounds = true

    /*
     var darkBlur = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
     var blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: darkBlur)

     blurView.frame = circle.bounds

     circle.addSubview(blurView)
     */
    preview.addSubview(circle)
    preview.addSubview(circle2)


    let spine = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 560, y: 110, width: 10, height: 110))
    func spineDraw(){
        spine.center = CGPoint(x: 560, y: 165)
        spine.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        spine.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        spine.clipsToBounds = true
        preview.addSubview(spine)
    }
    var shoulder = CGPoint(x: 400, y: 120)
    var rElbow = CGPoint(x: 410 + rElbowXGlobal.rElbowX, y: 170 + rElbowYGlobal.rElbowY)
    var rWrist = CGPoint(x: 410 + rWristXGlobal.rWristX, y: 195 + rWristYGlobal.rWristY)
    let rArm = UIBezierPath()
    rArm.lineWidth = 5
    func rArmDraw() {
        rArm.move(to: shoulder)
        rArm.addLine(to: rElbow)
        rArm.stroke()
        rArm.addLine(to: rWrist)
        rArm.stroke()
        rArm.close()
    }

    var lElbow = CGPoint(x: 390 + lElbowXGlobal.lElbowX, y: 170 + lElbowYGlobal.lElbowY)
    var lWrist = CGPoint(x: 390 + lWristXGlobal.lWristX, y: 195 + lWristYGlobal.lWristY)
    let lArm = UIBezierPath()
    lArm.lineWidth = 5
    func lArmDraw(){
        lArm.move(to: shoulder)
        lArm.addLine(to: lElbow)
        lArm.stroke()
        lArm.addLine(to: lWrist)
        lArm.stroke()
        lArm.close()
    }
    var hip = CGPoint(x: 400, y: 215)

    var rKnee = CGPoint(x: 410 + rKneeXGlobal.rKneeX, y: 250 + rKneeYGlobal.rKneeY)
    var rAnkle = CGPoint(x: 410 + rAnkleXGlobal.rAnkleX, y: 270 + rAnkleYGlobal.rAnkleY)
    let rLeg = UIBezierPath()
    rLeg.lineWidth = 5
    func rLegDraw(){
        rLeg.move(to: hip)
        rLeg.addLine(to: rKnee)
        rLeg.stroke()
        rLeg.addLine(to: rAnkle)
        rLeg.stroke()
        rLeg.close()
    }

    var lKnee = CGPoint(x: 390 + lKneeXGlobal.lKneeX, y: 250 + lKneeYGlobal.lKneeY)
    var lAnkle = CGPoint(x: 390 + lAnkleXGlobal.lAnkleX, y: 270 + lAnkleYGlobal.lAnkleY)
    let lLeg = UIBezierPath()
    lLeg.lineWidth = 5
    func lLegDraw(){
        lLeg.move(to: hip)
        lLeg.addLine(to: lKnee)
        lLeg.stroke()
        lLeg.addLine(to: lAnkle)
        lLeg.stroke()
        lLeg.close()
    }


    //debug grid
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    for i in 1...10 {
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: i*100, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: i*100, y: 1000))
        path.stroke()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: i*100))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 2000, y: i*100))
    }

    spineDraw()
    rArmDraw()
    lArmDraw()
    rLegDraw()
    lLegDraw()
    print("subview added")
}

}
}
```

Comment: Where are you removing an existing one after the first insertion?

Comment: I am not, is this an issue?

Comment: I'd be *very* careful about using a `UISlider` to create subviews. Ignoring the potential of how unintuitive such a thing is to a user, you can likely tie up the main thread because of *how many* times a slider's `valueChanged` is triggered. Also, either you are missing a "closing bracket" in you first `addSubview()` function or you are nesting `addSubview(preview:)` inside it, which can't be done. Finally, Swift offers some good alternatives to greatly cut down the size of your code - look into `enum`, `struct`, `switch` and even refactoring some things into classes. It helps debugging!

Comment: I see...My overall goal is to draw a line based on data received from a slider. I tried `setNeedsDisplay()` with no success, and thus tried to add a new subview to redraw. Is there a specific method I have to use to enable `addSubview()`? I am very inexperienced with graphics outside storyboard settings.